# String formatting c# decode?

Tags: c#, json, character-encoding, serialization

I have a string which looks like this `'%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22jim%22%7D'` When read from a cookie it is in fact a JSON object and should look like `{"id":1,"name":"jim"}`

Do I need to HTML decode the string to make it appear in the correct JSON notation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [**HttpUtility.UrlDecode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) in System.Web

Answer (score 1):

Also assuming your using .Net 3.5 check this article by ScottGu and follow up from Scott Longnecker that allows you to convert c# classes to json and viceversa.

http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/to-and-fromjson-extension-methods/

Comment: +1 Thank you. This answers my other question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178821/parsing-json-objects-to-c