# Parsing JSON objects in .Net 4 C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Parsing JSON objects to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178821/parsing-json-objects-to-c)
>   [What JSON library works well for you in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571168/what-json-library-works-well-for-you-in-net)

Is there a class for parsing JSON objects like XDocument for XML? If not what's the easiest way to parse and use JSON objects in C# 4.0?

Comment: There are already MANY questions that answer this question. Check them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using **[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)**?

Examples on their website :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are many library for json parsing in any language , and also there are many libraries for .net languages.You better to have a look at the bottom of this page:

[here](http://json.org/)